# Is it possible to influence how '_' lambda arguments are ordered?

Tags: scala, syntax

I have a statement which currently looks like this:

```
arrays.foldLeft(0)((offset, array) => array.copyTo(largerArray, offset))
```

It would be great to express it as follows, but this is not possible since foldLeft is designed to take the seed argument first:

```
arrays.foldLeft(0)(_.copyTo(largerArray, _))
```

This is purely superficial - I'm just curious!

*p.s. `copyTo` returns the next offset in this example.*

Comment: Personally, I don't think it is possible to write in more concise way than it is now.

Comment: In Scalaz at least there is `flip`. But in order to take advantage, you may need to use type annotations on your `_`s. In principle, though, usage would be `arrays.foldLeft(0)((_.copyTo(largerArray, _)).flip)`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks Debilski. Good to know, but in this case the original statement is probably most readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[The SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) seems to say "no".**

Section 6.23, *Anonymous Functions/Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions*:

> An expression (of syntactic category `Expr`) may contain embedded
>   underscore symbols `_` at places where identifiers are legal. Such an
>   expression represents an anonymous function where **subsequent**
>   occurrences of underscores denote **successive** parameters.

and

> **If** an expression `e` binds underscore sections `u1 , . . . , un`, **in this order**, it is equivalent to the anonymous function `(u'1 , ... u'n ) => e'` where each `u'i` results from `ui` by replacing the
>   underscore with a fresh identifier and `e'` results from `e` by
>   replacing each underscore section `ui` by `u'i`.

Emphasis is mine - it explicitly states in both relevant section that a preserved ordering is assumed.

Personally, I think it makes sense to enforce that, if "only" for readability reasons.